# Delegate gets destroyed

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, memory

I'm building a cross platform app, and 1 of those platforms is Macos.

Now the core of my code is written in C++, and Obj-C++.

I create a window like this:

```
NSWindow* window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(x, y, width, height) styleMask:macosWindowStyle backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:false];
```

but I wanted to listen to the window. I could've subclassed it, but I chose not to.

The other way to get events from the `NSWindow` was to set a delegate.

Now since my code was in Obj-C++, I couldn't have a C++ class inherit from a Obj-C protocol.

So, I created a Obj-C header, which implemented `NSWindowDelegate`.

Here it is:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject<NSWindowDelegate>

@end
```

I overrode `windowShouldClose` as such:

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(NSWindow *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Hello!");
    return true;
}
```

and in my Obj-C++ file, I did this:

```
NSWindow* window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(x, y, width, height) styleMask:macosWindowStyle backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:false];
SomeClass* someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
[window setDelegate:someClass];
```

However, when I pressed the X button, nothing happened.

I then proceeded to test the same thing in Swift, same result.

I then realized that the delegate was being **destroyed** because it was a weak reference.

My question is, how do I get around this?

Comment: Where are you creating the window (in a function, a method, etc.), and where are you storing it? Can you store the delegate in the same place? (e.g. as a variable as part of a class)

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out. I for some reason thought that I also couldn't have obj-c references in Obj-C++.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.
I for some reason thought I could not have Obj-C class pointers in my Obj-C++ code. I thought that was one of the limitations.